# For statment increment/decrement error

Tags: c++, function, for-loop

I am new to using C++. I have read books and I have been using the internet. In here - exercise 16 - https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Exercises/Iterations#EXERCISE_16)

I do not understand why my 'for' statement is not working, when it seems to meet the criteria. The full code is as below, and I will point out the bit that was not working for me:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void primecheck(int z)
{
    bool primes = true;
    // start at 1 because anything divisible by zero is an error
    for (int i=1; i<=z; i++)
    {
        if (z%i == 0)
        {
            // ignore if divisible by 1 or itself do nothing
            if ( i == z || i == 1)
            {}

            // if it can be divided by anything else it is not a prime
            else
            {
                primes = false;
                //break;
            }
        }
    }
    (primes == true) ? (cout << z << " is a prime number" << endl) : (cout << z << endl);
}

int main()
{
    int x;

    cout << "Enter a number to see if it is a prime number" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    for (x; x>0; x--)
    {
        primecheck(x);
    }
}
```

the working code is as above, but initially I had:

```
for (x; x<=1; x--)
{
    primecheck(x);
}
```

To me this made more sense, as I enter a high value, such as 5, and every loop I want it to reduce until it is 1. But whenever I did this, it just skipped the entire statement. Why does this happen?

Comment: If you enter `5` then `x <= 1` is `false` and the loop terminates

Comment: This isn't the problem, but for that output from `primecheck`, use an `if` statement. A ternary expression is for calculating a value. Using it purely for side effects is misuse.

Comment: Simply understand that middle expression in the for loop is a condition checking expression. If true proceed to body, else end the loop. Now if you enter 5, it will be greater than one, but your condition requires it to be greater than one. Hence the loop will end.

Comment: Alternatively, `cout << z << (primes ? " is a prime number" : "") << "\n";`. Also note that `X == true` is silly: It always returns `X`.

Comment: Thanks sheep & Pete Becker, I am just trying to use as many things as possible to gain experience. I understand it may be 'misuse' but I am still learning, so I will bare that in mind :)

Comment: If I were you, I'd break out my debugger, step through the code and observe the flow and how variables change along the way. That's usually *highly* enlightening.

Comment: I trust you know that your test for primality is *very* naive and quite inefficient.? *Much* better primality tests exist than just dividing by every number between 1 and the number to test (for one, you don't need to test if numbers greater than the square root of the target number divides it - and that's just the start).. If you are serious about testing primes I suggest you level up on your maths skills.

Comment: Jesper, thanks for that, I am aware it is a very simplistic model. However, I am focusing more on the workings of C++ rather than my mathematical implementation. regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (x; x<=1; x--)
{
    primecheck(x);
}
```

is equivalent to the following `while` loop:

```
x;
while (x<=1)
{
    primecheck(x);
    x--;
}
```

That is:

1. `x;` is pointless because it does nothing.
2. The condition in the middle part of a `for` loop is not a stop condition. The loop runs as long as it is true. When you enter a high value like `5`, `x<=1` is false from the beginning, and so the loop never runs. The condition must be true for it to run.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are saying now. Whilst the 'for' loop holds true it continually runs, but as soon as it is false / out of scope it stops.

Answer (score 2):

You would need this:

```
for (; x>=1; x--)
{
    primecheck(x);
}
```

What you had earlier said continue this for loop as long as x is <= 1. But your initial input would be greater than 1 (assuming, since you are checking for primality) so the loop would never run. In other words, if you enter any number greater than 1 (say 10) it would check the condition, 10<=1. That would evaluate to a false and loop would terminate

Comment: I am just trying to help. Please let me know of a reason of down-voting my answer to help me have better answers.

Comment: I originally downvoted your answer because initially it was just "*you need to do this: `code snippet`*" and it's not good code: `x;` does nothing.

Comment: Yes, but I did have an explanation. I added it. I thought of providing the sniper before the explanation so that the OP has something to work with. I added the explanation right away

Comment: Yes, but your answer still says "*you need to do `bad code`*". I don't like answers that recommend bad code.

Comment: How is that bad code? It is a simple for loop. x; is not pointless as it is the variable that holds the value OP wants the loop to run till

Comment: @melpomene - actually it is precisely what OP asked for. He messed up comparison operator and didn't see it.

Comment: Which is what I pointed out in my answer. I told the correct code for OP's incorrect one and then explained why that was incorrect.

Comment: @anon `x;` is pointless because it does nothing. It doesn't matter what variable you're using; `cout;` or `primecheck;` or `42;` would be equally pointless.